# How can I compile an electron app on a Windows environment to run on Raspberry PI?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, electron, node-modules, electron-packager

I've created an electron app on my Windows 10 computer. I've used electron-packager to package the app for linux using the armv7l architecture (Raspberry Pi 4). However, when I run it on the PI, it outputs an "invalid ELF header" error.

I understand that this is due to the node_modules having been built for windows. Is there any way that I can compile the app on Windows, but tell the compiler (electron-packager) to rebuild the node_modules for the target platform? I don't want to have to install anything on the PI prior to my application as the app needs to be a standalone executable. My main dependencies are serialport and tableify, other than electron itself.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you include your build arguements?  I think it would help#

Comment: @Simon I only used the one line as follows: electron-packager . pi-client --platform=linux --arch=armv7l. I'm new to electron and so don't fully understand how the compilation works on cross-platform

Comment: @DD_Pillay did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @whitefang I set up a new project on the Raspberry PI itself and compiled it on the PI

Comment: @DD_Pillay thanks for quick reply. After writing this question, I have also tried to compile on pi but it's too slow. Do you know any method to improve compilation time on Pi?

Comment: @whitefang It depends on how large your app is and how many dependencies you're using. I built and compiled my app as a backbone and then added my code afterwards. This way, you only compile it once

Comment: @whitefang Check the resources/app/ folder in your compiled project. You should be able to just add your files in there afterwards

Comment: @DD_Pillay thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by going into the `node_modules/@serialport/bindings cpp/prebuilds/linux` arm copied both the .node files into the `builds/release`. then followed the usual process to create .deb installer and it should work or you can try running `npm start` command (`electron .`)